# Is Measuring Feature Similarity Using Cosine a Valid Method?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision

It seems to be a common method in deep learning papers to measure the similarity of features coming from the backbone using cosine similarity.

However, in my opinion, since in most cases, the features coming from the backbone are put into the fc (fully connected) layer and applied to various downstream tasks, measuring with cosine does not seem to be of significant meaning.

The FC layer is heavily influenced not only by the angle but also by the norm of the feature, so even if the cosine similarity of the features of the two data is high, if there is a big difference in the norm, I predict that there will also be a big difference in the prediction.

Nevertheless, the method of measuring with cosine similarity is used quite frequently and seems to be accepted without much doubt. Why is that the case?

Comment: If the input to the FC layer gets scaled (same direction, but different norm), then its output is the same, merely scaled (if the activation function is linear or ReLU).

Comment: No similarity metric is perfect for all situations. The choice of a similarity metric is a situation-dependent trade-off.